# Как получить только последнюю строчку из JEditorPane

Tags: java, строки, swing

Есть окно, в нём `JEditorPane`. По нажатию кнопки нужно записать в `String g` только последнюю строчку из `JEditorpane` (то есть самую нижнюю). Возможно это без перебора символов в надежде найти 10 (перенос)? А вообще хотелось бы увидеть все возможные варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так

```
String g = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1);
```

где src - исходная строка.
Наверное, еще нужно проверка, что последняя строка не заканчивается переводом строки, из условия не ясно, могут ли быть такие строки.

Comment: спасибо большое! Прекрасно работает!